# Unable to display the tooltip and arctween transition ata a time in d3 pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

Hello I am trying to add arctween transition to my pie chart. I am able to show the tooltips and legends in my pie chart but when I try to add arctween transition to my pie chart the tooltip is not working. How to make this possible to display both the tooltip and the arctween transition in this pie chart.

```js
      (function(d3) {
        'use strict';
        var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50};
        var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 3;       
        var legendRectSize = 18;
        var legendSpacing = 4;

       var data = [
      {"IP":"192.168.12.1", "count":20}, 
      {"IP":"76.09.45.34", "count":40}, 
      {"IP":"34.91.23.76", "count":80},
      {"IP":"192.168.19.32", "count":16}, 
      {"IP":"192.168.10.89", "count":50}, 
      {"IP":"192.178.34.07", "count":18},
      {"IP":"192.168.12.98", "count":30}];
    

        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        var svg = d3.select('#chart')
          .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width+margin.left+margin.right)
          .attr('height', height+margin.left+margin.right)
          .append('g')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')');

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
          .innerRadius(0)
          .outerRadius(radius);

        var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
          .innerRadius(0)
          .outerRadius(radius + 5);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .startAngle(1.1*Math.PI)
      .endAngle(3.1*Math.PI)
      .value(function(d) { return d.count; });

        var tooltip = d3.select('#chart')                               
          .append('div')                                                
          .attr('class', 'tooltip');                                    
                      
        tooltip.append('div')                                           
          .attr('class', 'label');                                      
             
        tooltip.append('div')                                           
          .attr('class', 'count');                                      

        tooltip.append('div')                                           
          .attr('class', 'percent'); 

       var path = svg.selectAll('path')
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', arc)
            .attr('fill', function(d,i) { 
                return color(d.data.IP); 
            });
          path.on('mouseover', function(d) { 
           d3.select(this).transition()
                    .ease("exp")
                    .duration(3000)
                    .attrTween("d", tweenPie)
                    .duration(200)
                    .attr("d", arcOver)
                    .style('opacity',0.7)

                    function tweenPie(b) {
                      var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 1.1*Math.PI, endAngle: 1.1*Math.PI}, b);
                      return function(t) { return arc(i(t)); };
                    } 

            var total = d3.sum(data.map(function(d) {                   
              return d.count;                                           
            })); 

            var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.count / total) / 10; 
            tooltip.select('.label').html(d.data.IP);                   
            tooltip.select('.count').html(d.data.count);                
            tooltip.select('.percent').html(percent + '%');             
            tooltip.style('display', 'block');                                  
          });                                                           
                
          path.on("mouseout", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).transition()
                    .duration(100)
                    .attr("d", arc)
                    .style('opacity','1');
              tooltip.style('display', 'none'); 
              });                            

  var legend = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("width", radius+50)
    .attr("height", radius * 2)
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

 legend.append('rect')
    .attr('width', legendRectSize)
    .attr('height', legendRectSize)                                   
   .style('fill', color)
   .style('stroke', color);
  
  legend.append('text')
    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

      })(window.d3);
```

```css
      #chart {  
        margin-top: 100px;                                              
        position: absolute;  
        margin-right: 50px;
        margin-left: 50px;                                           
      }                                                                 
      .tooltip {                                                        
        background: #eee;                                               
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;                                    
        color: #900C3F;                                                    
        display: inline-block;                                                  
        font-size: 12px;                                                
        left: 600px;                                                    
        padding: 10px;                                                  
        position: absolute;                                             
        text-align: center;                                             
        top: 95px;                                                      
        width: 100px;                                                    
        z-index: 10;  
        opacity: 1;                                                 
      }                                                                 
      rect {
        stroke-width: 2;
      }
      path {
     stroke: #ffffff;
     stroke-width: 0.5;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing Pie Chart</title>
     <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Please help me. Above mentioned are the codes that I have tried yet. 
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: The tootip is getting dislplayed but not the arctween transition.

Comment: where have you applied transition to your pie the only transition i see is in your mouseover. Please see jsbin in below answer, I have made some changes from your code and let me know if thats what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this(http://jsbin.com/guqozu/edit?html,js,output):

```
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
  var htmlMsg="";
   div.transition()     
   .style("opacity", .9);       
    div.html(
    "IP :"+d.data.IP+""+"<br/>"+
    "Count : " +  d.data.count +"<br/>" + htmlMsg)
    .style("left",  (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
    .style("top",  (d3.event.pageY) + "px");    
    svg.selectAll("path").sort(function (a, b) { 
                  if (a != d) return -1;               
                  else return 1;                             
    });

    var endAngle = d.endAngle + 0.1;
    var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius   +10).endAngle(endAngle).startAngle(startAngle);
                        d3.select(this)
                           .attr("stroke","white")
                           .transition()
                           .ease("bounce")
                           .duration(1000)
                           .attr("d", arcOver)             
                           .attr("stroke-width",6);
                    })
                    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
               div.transition()        
                            .duration(500)      
                            .style("opacity", 0); 
                        d3.select(this).transition()            
                           .attr("d", arc)
                           .attr("stroke","none");
                    })
              .transition()
                .ease("bounce")
                .duration(2000)
                .attrTween("d", tweenPie);
```

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much. Going through your codes now. : )

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div = d3.select("#toolTip");

var data = [
      {"IP":"192.168.12.1", "count":20}, 
      {"IP":"76.09.45.34", "count":40}, 
      {"IP":"34.91.23.76", "count":80},
      {"IP":"192.168.19.32", "count":16}, 
      {"IP":"192.168.10.89", "count":50}, 
      {"IP":"192.178.34.07", "count":18},
      {"IP":"192.168.12.98", "count":30}];

var width = 300,
 height = 300;
var margin = {top: 15, right: 15, bottom: 20, left: 40},
 radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 10;
var legendRectSize = 18,
    legendSpacing = 4;
   

  var color = d3.scale.category20b();

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius);
    
    var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
          .outerRadius(radius + 10);

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .sort(null)
      .value(function(d) { return d.count; });

    var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius - 40)
      .innerRadius(radius - 40);
    
  var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
     .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var arcs = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie)
     .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");
    
   var arcs2 = svg.selectAll(".arc2")
      .data(pie)
     .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc2");

    
  arcs.append("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    var htmlMsg="";
       div.transition()  
              .style("opacity",0.9);  
          div.html(
           "IP :"+d.data.IP+""+"<br/>"+
           "Count : " +  d.data.count +"<br/>" + htmlMsg)
          .style("left",  (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
             .style("top",  (d3.event.pageY) + "px"); 

      svg.selectAll("path").sort(function (a, b) { 
          if (a != d) return -1;               
         else return 1;                             
      });
    
    var endAngle = d.endAngle + 0.1;
    var startAngle = d.startAngle - 0.1;
    var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
           .outerRadius(radius + 10).endAngle(endAngle).startAngle(startAngle);
               d3.select(this)
                  .attr("stroke","white")
                  .transition()
                  .ease("bounce")
                  .duration(1000)
                  .attr("d", arcOver)             
                  .attr("stroke-width",6);
           })

      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
             div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0); 
              d3.select(this).transition()            
                 .attr("d", arc)
                 .attr("stroke","none");
          })
      .transition()
       .ease("bounce")
       .duration(2000)
       .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

  function tweenPie(b) {
    b.innerRadius = 0;
    var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 0, endAngle: 0}, b);
    return function(t) { return arc(i(t)); };
  }

        var k=0;
  arcs2.append("text")
  .transition()
      .ease("elastic")
   .duration(2000)
   .delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 250;
   })
        .attr("x","6")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { if(d.data.count >0){ k = k+1; return d.data.count;} })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { if (k >1){return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ") rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";} else{return "rotate(-360)";} })
        .attr("font-size", "10px");
     

  function type(d) {
    d.count = +d.count;
    return d;
  }
  function angle(d) {
        var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
        return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
  }

 var legend = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("width", radius+50)
    .attr("height", radius * 2)
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

 legend.append('rect')
    .attr('width', legendRectSize)
    .attr('height', legendRectSize)                                   
   .style('fill', color)
   .style('stroke', color);
  
  legend.append('text')
    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
    .data(data)
    .text(function(d,i) { return d.IP; });
```

```css
     #chart {  
        margin-top: 100px;                                              
        position: absolute;  
        margin-right: 50px;
        margin-left: 50px;                                           
      }                                                                 
      .tooltip {                                                        
        background: #eee;                                               
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;                                    
        color: #900C3F;                                                    
        display: inline-block;                                                  
        font-size: 12px;                                                
        left: 600px;                                                    
        padding: 10px;                                                  
        position: absolute;                                             
        text-align: center;                                             
        top: 95px;                                                      
        width: 150px;                                                    
        z-index: 10;  
        opacity: 1;                                                 
    }                                                                 
    rect {
       stroke-width: 2;
    }
    path {
     stroke: #ffffff;
     stroke-width: 0.5;
 }
 div.tooltip {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 999;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #f4f4f4;
 border: 0px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 pointer-events: none;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #000;
 line-height: 16px;
 border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
 }

 .legend{
  margin-left: 300px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing Pie Chart</title>
     <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   </head>
 <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="toolTip" class="tooltip" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
     </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Thank you SiddP for suggesting some useful tips. Based on his codes and my research I have added a legend along with arctween and tooltip to this pie chart to make it complete. I hope this helps someone struggling over D3 pie chart.
Thank you stackoverflow. :}